# jsp page shows 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, servlets, intellij-14

Got a simple project setup, my goal is to load a jsp file:

I got my Controller with a RequestMapping for a jsp file.

```
package com.example.registrationFrom.control;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Control {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("Going home...");
    return "index"; // name JSP file
}
}
```

application.properties with a directory to the jsp

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

A jsp file in the project directory:

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

And I added the dependency (which is active)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I run the code and check localhost:8080 I get a 404.
I check the code a number of time but can't figure out why its not working.
please check out my [full code on github](https://github.com/LucasHartman/FormExample/tree/master/src/main)

Comment: Note that JSP will not work when being deployed as a standalone JAR file.

Comment: Why not, ultimately my goal is to make a web app, export it as a JAR file and upload it to AWS. If JSP don't work from a JAR file, what other options do I have?

Comment: JSP only works with WAR files. You can export your project as WAR and run it with `java -jar` as long as the file extension is `.war` but it seems to require a `*.war` file. In my experience, most people use Thymeleaf as a template engine in spring projects. JSP is mainly used in Java EE/Jakarta EE projects (without Spring).

Comment: thx @dan1st that was really informative. I will drop JSP and take a deep dive into Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse...

Did you check server.xml?

[tomcat's server.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvURZ.png)

i guess, maybe you should be check - this area

```xml
<Context docBase="helloworld" path="/testRoot" reloadable="true" .../>
```

TO

```xml
<Context docBase="helloworld" path="/" reloadable="true" .../>
```

Otherwise, if you're using a embeded-in tomcat of spring-boot, you should do maven clean and  install.
Because JSP is not static page (and not automatic load), so should be build again.

Comment: I'm using IntellIj, but last week my Ultimate trail-time stopped and started using the Community version. I'm also having trouble creating tables in MySQL. I don't know if this is related.

Comment: I have a similar experience in the IntelliJ community version. At that time, I solved it with the Ultimate version....